# SSL Support in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, soap, ssl

My application is a C# program running on .net 2.0 and is consuming some web services via https. This is implemented using `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`.

Now the provider of the services wrote, that in the next version they switch completely to SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0, removing the support for SSL 2.0.

Is this something that bothers me? Does .net 2.0 support this scenario or do I have to move to .net 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSLv2 is considered insecure, .NET 2.0 supports both SSLv3 and TLSv1.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find that page during my searches. New MSDN search is crap.